# Executable does not exist in /usr/local/bin, but it does in /usr/bin, yet it still fails

Tags: linux

I had to compile wine by hand for a certain patch, but I no longer need it.

So I did a `make distclean` (guess I should have done a `make uninstall` from the start, but oh well) and it was still there. The executable sitting in `/usr/local/bin/wine`

The other executable was sitting in `/usr/bin`, so I thought simply removing the other one would resolve this issue.

It did not.

Why not? And how do I fix it?

Comment: What *exactly* is "this issue"?

Comment: If `fails` is `command not found` while `/usr/bin` has the binary, it would be a good idea to include the output of `echo $PATH` in your question.

Comment: `bash: /usr/local/bin/wine: Bestand of map bestaat niet`

Answer (score 0):

In your `$PATH`, `/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin`. So an unwanted executable in `/usr/local/bin` will be found first and invoked instead of a wanted executable of the same name in `/usr/bin`.

As root (use `sudo` or `su`) delete the unwanted executable(s) from `/usr/local/bin`.

---

Update:

The message

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/wine: Bestand of map bestaat niet
```

Means that a command or a script has explicitly tried to execute `wine` using the wrong path `/usr/local/bin/wine`.

If you typed some command `foo` that produced this message, use `which foo` to find out where this command is, then use `file /full/path/to/foo` to find out if it is a script you can edit, delete or replace.

Comment: Yeah, that's the strange thing: I did. It's not there. Else it wouldn't say it couldn't find it, right? It's quite strange.

Comment: Some script is explicitly referencing wine by the full (but wrong) path `/usr/local/bin/wine`. Exactly what command did you type?